# How to set selectedItem in bottomNavigationView to nothing?

Tags: java, android

I currently have a bottom navigation with 3 items for my 3 activities. I have a separate button on one of the screens that opens a new activity. When this happens, I'd like to program it so none of the 3 options of the bottom navigation view are selected.

```
bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.______)
```

This is the line I use to select which icon I'd like to be shown as currently clicked. If I leave this line out of my activity, the first item of the bottom navigation view is selected by default.

Answer (score -1):

I think that it will be better for you to use fragments for this task.